# Error when trying to select a specific row in a list

Tags: r, loops, error-handling

I have the following script:

```
ng <- dat_c[,6:75]
names <- names(ng)
res <- list()
res_2o <-list
for (i in names) {
  res[[i]] <-aggregate(formula(paste(i, "~ola")), data = dat_c, FUN = "quantile" )
  res_2o[[i]] <- res[[i]][2,2]
  }
```

It's a simple script to get the quantiles of a list of variables which names are stored in "names.
The first part of the loop works perfectly. However when I try to just select the second row and second column of each element in the list with "res_2o" I get the following error:

```
Error in res_2o[[i]] <- res[[i]][2, 2] :
object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable
```

How can I solve this error? How can I just select the second row and column in each element of the list with the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
res_2o <-list()
```

You have to call list. Also, it's a bad idea to name a var `names`.